# hue issues migrating from sqlite to maria db

Tags: python, hadoop, cloudera, hue, mapr

As one for the steps for migrating sqlite to maria db.I am dumping data to a json file.I am having the error ImportError: libsasl2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
plz advise how to resolve the issue.

Below is the log:

```
(env)[mapr@anvmaprpd04:39:/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/bin] ./hue dumpdata >/tmp/sql-lite.json
[26/Apr/2017 13:55:36 +0000] settings     DEBUG    DESKTOP_DB_TEST_NAME SET: /opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/desktop/desktop-test.db
[26/Apr/2017 13:55:36 +0000] settings     DEBUG    DESKTOP_DB_TEST_USER SET: hue_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hue", line 12, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop==3.10.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 57, in entry
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    from desktop.lib.exceptions_renderable import PopupException
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/exceptions_renderable.py", line 28, in <module>
    import desktop.lib.django_util
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 40, in <module>
    import desktop.lib.thrift_util
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/thrift_util.py", line 24, in <module>
    import sasl
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sasl-0.1.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sasl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sasl.saslwrapper import *
  File "/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sasl-0.1.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sasl/saslwrapper.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _saslwrapper
ImportError: libsasl2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is an OS issue. You're either missing that library on your operating system or it's not in the path. So we'd need to know what OS this is. In RHEL derivatives for example you'd probably fix this running `yum install cyrus-sasl-lib`

Comment: The OS is Centos 7.3

Comment: [root@anvmaprpd04:38:/usr/lib64/sasl2] yum install cyrus-sasl-lib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cs.vt.edu
 * elrepo: iad.mirror.rackspace.com
 * elrepo-kernel: iad.mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: repos-va.psychz.net
 * updates: centos.aol.com
Package cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-20.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: I tried installing the package.it says package is already installed and its the latest.

Comment: assuming you have mlocate installed on your box try `locate libsasl2.so.2` make a note of the directory it's in and then check if when you do `echo $PATH` it's in there. If not, then you'll need to add it to the path.

Comment: /opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/libsasl2.so.2

Comment: and is that on the standard path?

Comment: I located it at /opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/libsasl2.so.2 .I can see the path when i did echo $PATH

Comment: [mapr@anvmaprpd04:8:~] echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/bin:/home/mapr/bin:/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/bin:/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/bu:/home/mapr/bin:/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/bin:/opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.10.0/build/env/lib/libsasl2.so.2:/home/mapr/bin

Comment: I reran the ./hue dumpdata >/tmp/sql-lite.json .still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake, not path, the library path. Usually handled by /etc/ld.so.conf It could be worth you copying the library file to one of the folders mentioned there

Comment: if that's empty look in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

Comment: Thanks.that helped.You are awesome.